# select minimum of one column maximum of another column

Tags: mysql, sql, max, min

I have data as below:

```
PID SID CID Price
1   1   1   18
2   1   1   19
3   1   2   10
4   2   2   22
5   2   2   21.35
6   3   2   25
7   3   7   30
8   3   2   40
```

I want to select rows for each SID where CID is minimum and Price is maximum.

Expected output:

```
PID SID CID Price
2   1   1   19
4   2   2   22
8   3   2   40
```

My query gives expected output. But since I am new to MySQL, I am not sure if it is the optimum way of doing it.

Query:

```
select a.PID, a.SID, a.CID, a.Price
from Products a
inner join (select SID as SID, min(CID) as CID_Min, max(Price) as Price_Max
            from Products
            group by SID) b
on a.SID=b.SID and
   a.CID=b.CID_Min and
   a.Price=b.Price_Max;
```

Edit #1:
Sorry but I observed for set of data as below, the query does not return any output:

```
PID SID CID Price
11  6   1   18
12  6   1   19
13  6   2   30
```

However expected output is:

```
PID SID CID Price
11  6   1   19
```

As minimum CID for SID=6 is 1. And from values SID=6 and CID=1, maximum value of Price is 19.

Any idea how to achieve it.

Is this query optimum:

```
select t.SID, t.CID, t.Price
from Products t
inner join
  (select p.SID as SID_max, p.CID as CID_max, max(p.Price) as Price_max
   from Products p
   inner join 
     (select SID as SID_min, min(CID) as CID_min
      from Products
      group by SID) p_min
   on p.SID=p_min.SID_min and
      p.CID=p_min.CID_min
   group by p.SID, p.CID
  ) p_max
on t.SID=p_max.SID_max and
   t.CID=p_max.CID_max and
   t.Price=p_max.Price_max
```

Comment: "My query gives expected output. But since I am new to MySQL, I am not sure if it is the optimum way of doing it." This is indeed one way how to do it.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Your query is just fine!

Comment: the question leads towards codereview think the question is better here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you ask me there is no need for the `JOIN` see [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18688/1)

Comment: You can use window functions in platforms that allow it. Look into `max() over ...`, etc.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @jarlh Really? We must have different definitions of just fine!

Comment: Hi @user9253718 I have exact same query as you posted. Did you find better optimum solution?

Answer (score 0):

Surely you want 12, 6, 1, 19 !?!?!?!?!?!?!

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM my_table a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.sid
            , x.cid
            , MAX(price) price 
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT sid
                   , MIN(cid) cid 
                FROM my_table 
               GROUP 
                  BY sid
            ) y 
           ON y.sid = x.sid 
          AND y.cid = x.cid 
        GROUP 
           BY sid
            , cid
     ) b 
    ON b.sid = a.sid 
   AND b.cid = a.cid 
   AND b.price = a.price;
+-----+-----+-----+-------+
| pid | sid | cid | price |
+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|  12 |   6 |   1 |    19 |
+-----+-----+-----+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks, even I wrote same query. I hope this is the optimum query.

Comment: Gosh, I hope so. There's a 'hack' way of writing the same thing using a lot less typing, but this is the textbook approach, and pretty fast. Another option is to use variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think only one *sub-query* is enough  to find the minimum `CID` for each `SID` and do the `JOIN`s with  *sub-query* to find the maximum `Price`

```
SELECT p.* FROM Products p
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT sid, min(cid) cid from Products
   GROUP BY sid
) pr ON pr.sid = p.sid AND
p.price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM Products WHERE sid = pr.sid AND cid = pr.cid)
```